# Launch Task Manager as minimized to the tray on login

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

I want Task Manager to be opened and minimized to the tray every time I log in. The current way I have it is with Task Scheduler, which launches the command `%windir\system32\cmd.exe /c start /min taskmgr.exe`, but this doesn't work correctly. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Windows 7? Just found this HowToGeek: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-a-shortcut-to-start-task-manager-in-minimized-mode/

Comment: You have a tiny mistake you your command. to correctly resolve path variable `windir` it has to be surounded by `%` signs from both sides. Like this:
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start /min taskmgr.exe
I have just checked and this command works ok on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a real path (e.g. C:\Windows\system32) instead of %windir\system32

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `cmd.exe` to launch `taskmgr`...? Using task scheduler is the recommended way to run such a task so well done. Task scheduler can append arguments (such as the `/min` you want) to the executable you are running - look in the `action` tab for your task.

Comment: I'm looking for any solution that gets the job done - doesn't have to be via `cmd`.